# ASUS Notebook F555LA-AB31 cannot connect wifi

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, wireless

I just bought ASUS Notebook F555LA-AB31 Core I3-5010U 4G 500G Intel HD DVDRW 15.6in.

The weird issue is I cannot connect wifi both on Ubuntu 14.04.5 and Ubuntu 16.04.03.

I change the windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 after I got it, it works fine for 2 weeks. After that, it always cannot connect to wifi. I tried many ways from Internet, it doesnot work. So, I change to Ubuntu 14.04, it has same problem. 
Then, I bring my laptop to fix, they said hardware is good.

After I run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

1: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

2: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

Additionally, I also cannot connect Ethernet, So I cannot download any software.
I have no idea how to fix it, could someone give me some experienced help.
I will appreciate you any help!!

Many thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: I already edit my question. Could you give me some ideas about that?